# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean Error on varchar column

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, ado.net, odbc, npgsql

I am getting this error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.Couldn't store <No> in meetsstd Column.  Expected type is Boolean
```

When I am running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM work_nylustis_2013_q3.nylustis_details WHERE siteid = 'NYLUSTIS-155718'  LIMIT 50
```

From this code:

```
Adapter.SelectCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(SQL, MLConnect)
Adapter.Fill(subDT)   ' This line throws error
```

The meetsstd field is a varchar(3) and it does store either a 'Yes' or a 'No' value. How is this getting this confused with a boolean - a varchar should not care whether is holds 'Yes', or 'Si', or 'Oui'? And it only happens on 27 records out of the 28,000 in the table.

I usually blame npgsql for this kind of strangeness, but the last entry in the stack trace is: System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item(Int32 record, Object value)

Any clues?

Thanks!
Brad

Comment: What do the 27 bad records look like?

Comment: Just like all the rest. There is no visible difference in character (obviously different in content.)

Answer (score 1):

To check if it is problem with database or with driver you can reduce problem to one row and column using your current environment:

```
SELECT meetsstd FROM work_nylustis_2013_q3.nylustis_details WHERE sitenum=1
```

(of course you must change `sitenum` into primary key)

Then try such query using `psql`, `pgAdmin` or some JDBC/ODBC based general editor.

If `psql` shows such record which raises error with your Npgsql based application then problem is with Npgsql driver or problem is with displaying  query results.

If other tools shows such strange errors then problem is with your data.

Have you changed type of `meetsstd` field? Mayby you try to show it on some grid and this grid used Boolean field which was converted to `Yes/No` for displaying?